# WooCommerce - change price based on product_id, width and height

Tags: height, width, woocommerce

how can I set my own price in WooCommerce, based on product ID and  numbers from added 2 input fields  on my single-product/price.php ?
Here is example where i can target price :
http://pastebin.com/BZUV6csG#
But what about inputs? How can i achieve something like that:

```
if product_id= a or d or g 
and inputWidth >=40 and <=60 
and inputHeight >=60 and <=80
return product_price = my Value
```

I try many plugins already, but i have >100products 
in different price cathegory based on id/product name) and with >150 price 
variation based on width and height
Would you , please help me target those 2 inputs?
I added them using this plugin:
https://github.com/nextime/woocommerce-better-product-addons

Comment: possible duplicate of [WooCommerce - update price from number input fiels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27335602/woocommerce-update-price-from-number-input-fiels)

Comment: Well, no one can help me i guess, but i add my own form to woocommerce product page from here : http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-build-your-own-wordpress-contact-form-and-why/ so, at least maybe someone will know how to integrate form validation with wooCommerce?